# What is the advantage of using extension functions as function parameters?

Tags: kotlin

I had a closer look at Kotlin's scoping functions lately and I saw that sometimes they expect an extension function as parameter. Just take **also** and **apply** as an example:

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    block()
    return this
}

public inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    block(this)
    return this
}
```

From a consumer's point of view it seems like there is not much of a difference between the two, I can call them pretty much in the same way:

```
fun main() {
    val logger = Logger.getLogger("Test")
    logger.info("A").apply {
        logger.info("B")
    }.also {
        logger.info("C")
    }
}
```

So I was wondering what am I missing here? Is there a pattern or best practice in Kotlin when to use extension functions in higher-order functions and what exactly are the benefits?

Answer (score 5):

> From a consumer's point of view it seems like there is not much of a difference between the two, I can call them pretty much in the same way

This is because you're not taking advantage of the receiver or parameter here. You're using your existing variable `logger` instead of whatever receiver `apply` provides.

One of the main points of scope functions is to use them on expressions when you don't have a variable yet:

```kotlin
Logger.getLogger("Test").apply {
    info("A") // the logger is provided as `this` here
}

Logger.getLogger("Test2").also { logger ->
    logger.info("A") // the logger is provided as parameter here
}

Logger.getLogger("Test2").also {
    it.info("A") // using the implicit `it` parameter
}
```

As you probably noticed in the examples above, higher-order functions that take a lambda with receiver will provide the value differently to the caller of the function. Within the block, the parameter will be available as `this` in case of a receiver, and as a parameter otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of `Logger.info`, they are indeed not much different. `info` returns `Unit`, so `T` is `Unit`, and `Unit` is a rather bad example.

Consider a better example:

```
val person = Person().apply {
    firstName = "John"
    lastName = "Smith"
    age = 30
}

// vs

val person = Person().also {
    it.firstName = "John"
    it.lastName = "Smith"
    it.age = 30
}
```

Both of these do the same thing, namely the following, but in one single statement:

```
val person = Person()
person.firstName = "John"
person.lastName = "Smith"
person.age = 30
```

But because the lambda of `apply` is an "extension function", or in other words, has `Person` as the *receiver*, you do not need any additional qualification (like `it.` or `person.` etc) to refer to members of `Person`. You can refer to them simply by their *simple names*, e.g. just "`firstName`".

This is why `apply` is often used to set up objects' properties, or to apply changes to an object, because it is convenient to not have to write `it.` many time.

On the other hand, the lambda parameter of `also` has `Person` as a parameter, so to refer to its members, you need `it.xxx`, `it.yyy` etc. `it` refers to the lambda's sole parameter.

This makes `also` suitable for doing an additional action on the result of an expression, because it is natural to say ", and `also` do this on `it`".